# ¿Cómo obtener la suma de una columna en MySQL, y mostrar sus otros datos en 1 sola consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedure

En un procedimiento almacenado, necesito realizar una suma de columnas y a la vez mostrar los otros campos, suena fácil si se hace por separado, un procedimiento para obtener la suma, y el otro para obtener todos los datos... El tema es que si se trata hacer todo en un solo procedimiento almacenado es mejor y es aquí de su ayuda.

Aquí tengo mi código

```
SELECT sum(tpc.cantidad) as stock FROM tb_ejemplo1 AS tpc 
inner JOIN tb_ejemplo2 as tm
ON tpc`codigo = tm.codigo where tm.indicador = 'ABC';
```

Bajo esa consulta me retorna solamente la columna stock con la suma, al momento de agregar tpc.*, solamente me muestra 1 solo registro y desconozco como podría hacerlo para que muestre los demás registros... Gracias!!!

Comment: si queres las sumas, tenes que decirle como agrupar... por cual columna queres agrupar todos esos resultados?

Comment: @gibianchi me equivoqué en el requerimiento es solo mostrar registros sin la suma jajaja, pero gracias de todos modos 

Comment: Si ese no es el requerimiento, entonces ¡editá tu pregunta!

Comment: si es mostrar todo sin suma, es un simple select... ya ni es duda jajaja

Comment: @padaleiana tú andas puro dando jugo y psicopatenado mis post, nunca aportas nada más que alegar.

Comment: Hola. Puede que [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) sea útil en este caso. No obstante, faltan detalles en tu pregunta, por ejemplo, no dices qué campos adicionales quieres obtener, cómo quieres esos campos, por qué columna(s) debe agruparse, etc. Tampoco dices qué problemas o errores tienes con tu código. Qué resultados obtienes y qué esperas obtener. Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta. Y no seas injusto con usuarios que comentan en tu pregunta con intención de ayudarte a resolver el problema.